# fractal tree recursion issue

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to get back into coding and thought writing a quick little fractal tree in js would help, but i'm obviously doing something wrong. Below is my code and following it is a very similar code that I found that basically uses the same logic. My code was working until i added the second call of draw () with the negative angle so that the tree grows on the left as well. I would love to learn why this second call is breaking the recursion.

thank you in advance

my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>fractal tree</title>
<style>
    #myCanvas{
        border:1px solid black; 
    }
</style>
<script>
    var x =0;
    var y =0;
    var startx;
    var starty;
    var length;
    var pi = Math.PI;
    var ang = pi/4;
    var ctx;
    var canvas;
    window.onload = function setup(){
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        startx = canvas.width/2;
        starty = canvas.height;
        length = 300;   
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.translate(startx,starty);
        draw(ctx,startx,starty,length,ang);
    }
    function draw(ctx,x,y,length,angle) {
        if(length < 1){
            return;
        }
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.translate(0,-length);
        ctx.rotate(angle);
        draw(ctx,x,y,length*.67,angle);
        draw(ctx,x,y,length*.67,-angle);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="600px">

    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

other code i found(which does work)

```
function draw(startX, startY, len, angle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(startX, startY);
  ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI/180);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -len);
  ctx.stroke();

  if(len < 10) {
    ctx.restore();
    return;
  }

  draw(0, -len, len*0.8, -15);
  draw(0, -len, len*0.8, 15);

  ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: I want to add a note that i know this is not the most efficient way to do this, but at this point all i would like to know is why the recursion is breaking. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

It is not breaking, it is just taking a long time. Note that in order to draw "the same thing on the other side", you would need to duplicate the `draw` call in `onload`. By duplicating the `draw` call in the `draw` call, you increased the fractal dimension, made a very different kind of drawing, and increased the drawing time exponentially.

Comment: Weird, i've let it load on my browser for half an hour with nothing to show. plus it froze my dreamweaver once. good idea to just have a 2nd call in onload but is there really no way to efficiently put the 2nd call within itself?

Comment: Try to sketch it to see what's going on: either reduce the size of the thing, or change `if(length < 1)` to `if(length < 5)` to see what's going on quicker.

Comment: you were right. somehow i must have been running out of memory. I changed it to if(length < 20) and it worked. I did also find out i can't just call it from onload() as that would only give me one "fork" and the rest would be single branches. so i'll have to incorporate the save() and restore() methods.

Comment: sorry, one more question. Does the return in the if statement break the whole draw function or only the recursive one?

Comment: It acts as a terminal case for the recursion. Every time it tries to go too tiny, it will finish there.

Answer (score -1):

+1 Amadan. If you're interested in seeing how fractal trees have been approached and implemented in Javascript using P5js you can take a look at [Daniel Shiffman's Coding Challenge](https://youtu.be/0jjeOYMjmDU). He does a great job of walking through how he does it step by step.

Comment: thank you sspboyd. That's actually the video that inspired me to try it. I just wanted to do it in pure Javascript.